# Computed from constant expressions type hints

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylance

I would like to define class properties in Python using a dictionary to map property names to their corresponding types. However, when using a naive approach, Pylance reports an error `Illegal type annotation: variable not allowed unless it is a type alias`. Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```py
from enum import Enum, auto

class Keys(Enum):
    Integer = auto()
    String = auto()

types = {Keys.Integer: int, Keys.String: str}

class MyClass:
    int_property: types[Keys.Integer] # Error is reported here
    str_property: types[Keys.String]  # Error is reported here
```

Is there a way to achieve this kind of structure while still getting correct type hints from Pylance?

Comment: Could you elaborate on _why_ you want to do this? Maybe the underlying problem can be solved with a different approach altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Type hints are evaluated statically, and your snippet requires actually executing code to find the correct type.

If you're trying to add a layer of indirection to your typing, in case you want to change them later, you can use type aliases:

```
NumberType = int
StringType = str

class MyClass:
    int_property: NumberType
    str_property: StringType
```

You can then change `NumberType = float` and all properties depending on it will be updated correspondingly. You can think of it as using the local scope as the dictionary; the variable names are the keys, and the aliased types are the values.